# Disable rewrite for page parameter in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

Actually when doing a search the url i'm getting is something like example.com/page/2/?s=searchphrase but I want to have a url like example.com/?s=searchphrase&page=2.

I already know that this is done by the internal rewrite engine of wordpress.
I have dived into the WP_Rewrite class @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rewrite/.

How could I archieve this, so that the query param page will not be transformed into a virtual folder?

Answer (score 0):

i havent tested it, but i think this will do the job

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp/remove_query_var/

use like:

```
public function shalior_remove_page_query() {
/* @var WP $wp */
global $wp;

// Remove query var.
    $wp->remove_query_var( 'page' );
}
```

this hook should also work:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query_vars/